# Secure connection to docker image using port 80?

Tags: docker

I am running a docker-image on a VPS. The image uses port 80 for front end login (and I can not use 443 since its occupied for other purposes).

Anyhow, I feel uncomfortable to log in on port 80 since the password easily can be snatched that way.

How can I make a secure front end connection so that any password typed in will be encrypted when I try to login, even though I use port 80 (http). I guess a SSH tunnel would work somehow - is that possible?

Comment: Why can't you use https? You *don't* have to use port 443, and a single web server can handle multiple vhosts, so you could set up a vhost for your docker image and proxy requests through whatever webserver you're using

Comment: You could use `nginx-proxy` as proxy and `letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` to automatically get free certificates.

Answer (score 1):

The https 443 port number is not "magic", you can use any port from 1-65535 you like. There are only 2 conditions:

1. Both the server and the client have to (agree to) use the same port number.
2. Ports in the range 1-1023 are "well known ports" which are assigned worldwide to specific applications or protocols. If you use one of these port numbers, you may run into conflicts with the "well known" applications. Ports from 1024 on are freely useable.

As an example, you could use port 30443.
Just add a :30443 at the end of url in the browser like "https://www.myip.com:30443".

set up docker to expose the 443 port of the docker image to the machines 30443 port

if your docker image only support non-https access via port 80 you might need to setup a proxy that secures the 80 port of the docker image - nginx-proxy and letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion can help - but that's another subject

see https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this. I will look into it and try this solution.